# Do Amazon searches with CURL (or any programmatic way)?

Tags: web, curl, web-scraping, get, libcurl

I'm trying to get Amazon search results programatically.

For instance, if you go to `amazon.com` and type `computer`, the resulting URL is `https://www.amazon.com/s?k=computer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2`, but running

`curl https://www.amazon.com/s?k=computer&ref=nb_sb_noss_2`

gives back an error page.

Is there a way to use `curl`, or any programmatic way (except the API) to fetch Amazon search results?

Comment: Just use postman

Answer (score 0):

Amazon does provide API access to developers.  The top of the output from the curl command you posted reads as follows:

```
 To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact 
api-services-support@amazon.com. For information about migrating 
to our APIs refer to our Marketplace APIs at
https://developer.amazonservices.com/ref=rm_5_sv, or our Product 
Advertising API at 
https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/advertising/api/detail/main.html/ref=rm_5_ac 
for advertising use cases.
```

Comment: The question is about doing it *without* using the API, obviously.

Comment: Your original post says:  "Is there a way to use curl, or any programmatic way, for that matter, to fetch Amazon search results?"        "...Any programmatic way" would include using the API.

Comment: If I had access to the API I wouldn't be using curl...